# How To Perform Data Driven Testing in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing, data-driven-tests

I am writing UI Tests in Xcode and want to do so using data driven testing.  How can this be accomplished using Xcode's new UI Testing Framework XCUI?  The test cases would be of the following form:

```
class StepUnitFormatterTests: XCTestCase {
//> (0, "0 steps")
//> (1, "1 step")
//> (2, "2 steps")
//> (999, "999 steps")
//> (1000, "1,000 steps")
//> (1000000, "1,000,000 steps")
//> (3.3, "3 steps")
//> (-5, "0 steps")
func testFormat(_ numberOfSteps: Double, _ expected: String) {
    XCTAssertEqual(StepUnitFormatter().format(numberOfSteps), expected)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As David Nix points out in his post [Table Driven Tests in Swift](https://davidnix.io/post/table-driven-tests-in-swift/) you can use an array of tuples for your test data and then loop over this array.

For example

```
let tests: [(input: Int, expected: String)] = [
    (input: 0, expected: "0 steps"),
    (input: 1, expected: "1 step"),
    (input: 2, expected: "2 steps"),
    (input: 999, expected: "999 steps"),
    (input: 1000, expected: "1,000 steps"),
    (input: 1000000, expected: "1,000,000 steps"),
    (input: 3.3, expected: "3 steps"),
    (input: -5, expected: "0 steps")
]

let formatter = StepUnitFormatter()

func testFormat() {
    for test in tests {
        XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(test.input), test.expected)
    }
}
```

You can use this pattern in UI tests as well.

In addition to David's post I add a third column which describes the intention of a test:

```
let steps: [(input: Double, expected: String, rationale: String?)] = [
    ...
    (input: 3.3, expected: "3 steps", rationale: "Decimal steps must be rounded"),
    (input: -5, expected: "0 steps", rationale: "Negative steps must be 0") 
    ...
]
```

This is a little bit wordy but helps your future self understanding the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

**UITests** aren't the right type of test for your case. You typically use UITests to simulate a user's interaction with your app. For example to test that pressing a button brings you to the next screen.

To test if your `StepUnitFormatter` is working correctly you would typically write a **UnitTest**:

Your test function will not work, because in UnitTest (and UITests) classes the testing functions do not allow parameters.

In your special case the function could look like this:

```
func testStepUnitFormatter() {
    let formatter = StepUnitFormatter()
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(0), "0 steps")
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(1), "1 step")
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(2), "2 steps")
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(1000), "1,000 steps")
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.format(3.3), "3 steps")
    // etc.
}
```

But again, this code is part of a UnitTest class. To do the same with a UITest you would have to test you formatter by actually running the app and using the user interface to enter all the different values that you want to test. That's why you should use UnitTests instead of UITests in this case.